# SVM algorithm does not run in Google Earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, classification

I am running a classification code in GEE and getting the following errors while trying to print Validation overall accuracy and mapping the classification result:

```
> Number (Error)
The service is currently unavailable.

SVM_classification: Layer error: The service is currently unavailable.
```

I am comparing three algorithms in this script: RF, SVM, and CART.
The RF and CART run without any problem. SVM takes a long time and at the end does not run at all.
Here is the link to my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/84875d74a1b380dbed12cee047758bed?accept_repo=users%2Fessepratico%2FPratico_et_al_RemoteSensing_2021

Comment: The link you shared seems to run without a problem here.

Comment: @Jobbo90 Thank. So it might be a problem from my computer or internet? Because I really receive this error messages!

Comment: Not your computer but perhaps your internet, not sure there. You could try to test your approach first. Also I see you generate a lot of median composites which you are not using. Turn everything off you don't need, your just wasting computations there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script runs well from my side and outputs the RF, SVM, and CART overall accuracies without any problem. However, if you encounter time out on the SVM classification the best solution is to export your value. I have added the code to export the RF, SVM, and CART accuracies to your script. Also added the error matrix code to show the error in the various landuse classes classification. Find the complete script here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/021fb84b2e2bf7952081660575f092dc?accept_repo=users%2Fessepratico%2FPratico_et_al_RemoteSensing_2021